# There do not alert the jQuery size

Tags: jquery, html

In my HTML body I have three div like bellow:

This is my index.js:

```js
$(function(){
  
  alert($('.box').size());
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>selector</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    box1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box3
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But there do not show the size of jQuery objects.

Comment: And did you read the error message? Read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/size/)? Both are quite clear.

Comment: I follow a video tutorial. it use `.seze()`.

Comment: It probably doesn't use `.seze()`. It might use `.size()` if it's a **really** old tutorial (I would look for something newer). Again: Both the error message and the documentation are quite clear about what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The `size()` method is deprecated in jQuery 1.8,

You should use `length` property to check its count:

```
alert($('.box').length);
```

In [jQuery document](https://api.jquery.com/size/):

> Returns: Integerversion
>   deprecated: 1.8, removed: 3.0

You can see it was removed in jQuery `3.0`, so you can not use it in your CDN `3.3.1`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```js
$(function(){
  alert($('.box').size());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>selector</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    box1
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box2
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    box3
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```